# Unterschied zwischen "Fazit" und "Nachwort"

Tags: difference

> **Fazit:** *zusammenfassend festgestelltes Ergebnis; Schlussfolgerung; Resümee*
>
>   **Nachwort:** *einem Schriftwerk, einer größeren schriftlichen Arbeit nachgestellter, ergänzender, erläuternder Text*

Was ist der Unterschied zwischen dem Fazit und dem Nachwort einer wissenschaftlichen Arbeit. Sind beide Begriffe austauschbar? Oder können beide gleichzeitig vorhanden sein?

Comment: Siehst Du in den Erklärungen keinen Unterschied? Sollen wir die Sätze übersetzen oder mit eigenen Worten wiederholen?

Comment: Ein Fazit ist *inhaltlich* definiert: es fasst wesentliche Punkte zusammen. Oft steht es am Schluss, aber nicht immer. Ein Nachwort ist *formal* definiert: es steht am Ende eines Werkes und ist vom Haupttext abgehoben. Oft zieht es ein Fazit, aber nicht immer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tl;dr: Fazit und Nachwort sind nicht austauschbar; sie haben unterschiedliche Zwecke, sind in unterschiedlichen Textgattungen vertreten und stehen in einem unterschiedlichen Verhältnis zum Hauptwerk. Sie können jedenfalls theoretisch gleichzeitig vorhanden sein.

So, jetzt ausführlich:

Ein **Nachwort** dürfte eher im Bereich der Belletristik und weniger im Sachbuchbereich üblich sein. Das Nachwort enthält dort üblicherweise Informationen über den Autor und die Entstehung des Werks, in der Regel aber keine Zusammenfassung, und erst recht kein "Ergebnis". [Wikipedia nennt](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nachwort) - m.E. zutreffend -

> "Verständnishilfe, Interpretation, Darlegung der Intention oder (..) Widmung"

als Zweck des Nachworts. Alle diese Punkte dürften im Sachbuchbereich eher selten sein (bzw. werden wie die Widmung nicht in einem eigenen, dem Werk nachgestellten Textteil erfolgen). Insbesondere dürfte *Urheber* des Fazits (eines wissenschaftlichen Werks bzw. Sachbuches) regelmäßig der Autor des Werkes selber sein; ein Nachwort hingegen wird häufig eher vom Herausgeber oder Übersetzer des Werks stammen (ausgenommen die Widmung, die eher vom Autor des Hauptwerks stammen wird und auch ein eigenes Vorwort darstellen kann).

Das zeigt, dass das Nachwort eine ganz andere Intention als ein Fazit hat. Das Nachwort liefert eher Metainformationen über Autor und Werk, das Fazit das Werk selber in einer extrem komprimierten, evtl. auf das Ergebnis reduzierten Form. Es handelt sich daher m.E. um  verschiedene Textgattungen, die regelmäßig nicht austauschbar sind.

Fazit und Nachwort können theoretisch gleichzeitig vorhanden sein, was aber eher in seltenen Fällen anzutreffen sein wird - etwa wenn eine wissenschaftliche Arbeit, die ein Fazit des Autors enthält, mit einem Nachwort des Herausgebers neu erscheint.

**[Vorworte](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prolog_(Literatur))** (ok, danach war nicht gefragt) hingegen werden wahrscheinlich eher im Sachbuchbereich anzutreffen sein, im belletristischen Bereich wohl em ehesten noch bei wissenschaftlichen Editionen.

Und last but not least sei auf die völlig unterschätzte Gattung des **Zwischenworts** verwiesen, etwa jenes des Altbundespräsidenten Herzog in der berüchtigten "Festschrift für [Nagelmann](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedrich_Gottlob_Nagelmann)"...

Answer (score 0):

Ein *Nachwort* **zieht** sehr oft ein ***Fazit*** einer schriftlichen Arbeit - eben, weil dort eine Zusammenfassung drinsteht (ein Fazit kann natürlich auch anders transportiert werden, z.B. mündlich).

Daher sind die Begriffe natürlich nicht austauschbar, genauso wenig, wie *Milch* und *Milchflasche* austauschbar sind. Das eine ist, "was drin ist", das andere "Inhalt und Verpackung".